# Solving a Cournot oligopoly game with N firms

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

This is the full question: **Find all pure strategy Nash equilibria of the Cournot oligopoly game with $N$ firms facing linear demand $P = a − Q$ when the total cost for each firm is $c_i(q_i) = q_i^2$.**

My understanding is that:

$$\pi_i = q_i(a − Q) - q_i^2$$

$$\max_{q_i} \quad q_i(a − Q) - q_i^2$$

Therefore, the FOC:

$a - Q - 2q_i = 0$

This FOC can be derived for each firm.

This is the part that I get stuck at. How do you add all the FOCs of $N$ firms together? Thank you!

Comment: I think your FOC is wrong. Isn't $Q=q_1+q_2+q_3+\ldots+q_N$? But then this term should be differentiated WRT $q_i$ too.

Comment: This question is crossposted on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017877/cournot-oligopoly-game-with-n-firms). And since that is where questions about adding equations belong, I am voting to close it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017877/cournot-oligopoly-game-with-n-firms

Answer (score 1):

Your FOC is wrong.

So $$\max_{q_i} \quad q_i(a − \sum_{j=1}^nq_j) - q_i^2$$

$$\implies \max_{q_i} \quad aq_i − q_i\sum_{j=1}^nq_j - q_i^2$$

The real FOC is

$$a - \sum_{j\neq i}q_j - 2q_i - 2q_i = 0.$$

Comment: This solution method would be correct if the OP had calculated the correct FOC to begin with.

Comment: Oh dammit you're right.

Comment: It should be fixed.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry I think you might want to try again :)

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry Or maybe not. After all, it is a crossposted off-topic question with no visible effort...

Comment: @denesp I'm traaaaaash *headdesk* (If this is wrong again please just delete this answer out of my misery ayy lmao)

Comment: Soooo torn between editing and voting to delete.

Comment: oh editing works too

Comment: FAM that's what I had at the end @denesp you charlatan

Comment: :) I rolled it back. But look, you are correct at the end of the answer but incorrect at the beginning. I mean you do not even give the same solution via the two methods.

Comment: The problem with this new version is that you impose symmetry before differentiating. That means that you are allowing $i$ to change not only his own quantity, but also everyone else's! My advice would be to write profit at $qi[a-Q(q_i)]-q_i^2$ and differentiate with the product rule (we know $Q'(q_i)=1$). You should get the FOC $a-Q(q_i)-q_iQ'(q_i)-2q_i=a-Nq_i-3q_i=0$ (where the first equality follows by imposing symmetry).

Comment: I am really out of it today. I'll roll it back to denesp's edit >o< Thanks for your patience.